# How to justify RPA (random phase approximation)?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, feynman-diagrams, perturbation-theory, approximations

The [Random Phase Approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_phase_approximation) (RPA) is a technical method used in field theory to account for interactions when calculating correlation functions. It consists of only keeping a certain class of diagrams when doing a perturbative calculation of a certain function, such as a susceptibility or dielectric function.

Is there a simple mathematical justification to this method, other than "it is simple and it fits experimental data", which is already a good justification? Why don't we include the vertex corrections and other self-energy terms?

Comment: See Altland-Simons page 216. Basically, the RPA Feynman diagrams have the largest contribution in the limit of high electron density.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for ! If you want to elaborate your comment into an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 5):

RPA is the first order approximation in $1/N$ (which is often called the Large-$N$ expansion), where $N$ is the number of fermions in the system. In the system with spin up and spin down, then $N=2$. Therefore, RPA is exact in the hypothetical system with $N\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. In usual theories $N$ is no larger than $2$ or $3$, so is the limit $N \rightarrow \infty$ really relevant ?